# How to list all scripts called by a master script?

Tags: shell, shell-script

I want to list all scripts (recursively) which are being called by a master script. For example:

```
master.sh

a.sh >> this script calls a1.sh, a2.sh, a3.sh etc
b.sh >> this one calls b1.sh, b2.sh, something.sh, etc.sh..
c.sh > similarly.
```

This is like the tree command for scripts.

The output could be like

```
master.sh
-a.sh
 |- a1.sh
    |-something.sh
    |-something_else.sh
-a2.sh
 |-x.sh
 |-y.sh
-a3.sh
...
```

Comment: If you really don't find anything else, you could always add things into your scripts (or making a copy) that say "if(you're being called by script:check_script_tree) { display the name of this script; call scripts; } else { do the script normally; }". A huge pain, but well, if you're desperate, you can do that. My teacher calls it making a program's skeleton. But there's probably something easier.

Comment: Yeah, I did not find anything else. It was mentioned somewhere to add  "echo $0 > somefile.log" to *all* scripts, just to get a list of the files. That would be insane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is `pstree`. It will list all running processes in a nice tree format. You can use the `-H` option to highlight a specific command (given as a [PID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier)). In the example below I am using `pgrep` to get the PID of `master.sh` :

```
pstree -H `pgrep master.sh` |grep -A 2 master.sh 
 |-bash---master.sh-+-a1.sh---something.sh
 |                  |-a2.sh
 |                  |-a3.sh
```

---

The `ps` command can also do what you need, the `ps` command can do *everything* except brew a good cup of coffee:

```
ps xjf
```

This will list all processes launched by `master.sh` (in fact, it will list *all* processes, including those launched by `master.sh`) in a tree-like format:

```
\_ master.sh
|   \_ a1.sh
|       \_ something.sh
|       \_ something.sh
|   \_ a2.sh
|   \_ a3.sh
```

I am only showing the relevant output here, the above command will also give you various other pieces of information such as the PID, process status etc etc.

Comment: Yup, the standard UNIX tools are impressive if cryptic. If you have nothing better to do over the next weekend and can't find "War and Peace", try reading through the 1230 lines of `man ps` :).